# Android - How to track the events of an Application

Tags: android

I want to detect what some certain application is accessing in my android phone . I mean , i know what permissions it have ! but i want to see when did it try to access what thing . like did it open my gallery , did it see my location and when. I have no idea where to start . I will really appreciate if someone helps

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a custom rom to do this.  Which would actually be an interesting project.  But there's no way to know what APIs its accessing when, except from the framework.

Comment: and is there a way to detect all the events that are happening in my smartphone ? All the things which are being accessed by any app? [without knowing which apk is doing it]

Comment: I suppose making a BroadcastReceiver that listens for every, single Intent... but that's assuming you know ALL the possible Intent actions.  Doesn't include custom ones from user-built apps.

Comment: That would inform you of what was happening.  It wouldn't inform you of what apps were accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to monitor your DDMS, and check all logs. If you are patient enough, you can find something you want:)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the closest you can get without creating a custom ROM, if your ROM already supports it, is to use [systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html).

Systrace captures and displays execution times of your applications processes and other Android system processes. The tool combines data from the Android kernel such as the CPU scheduler, disk activity and application threads to generate an HTML report that shows an overall picture of an Android device’s system processes for a given period of time.

Comment: I have never used systrace, although thankyou for the comment . i will see if it helps me